# Calculate intersection of two segments

Tags: algorithm, intersection

I have two segments. Every segment will be either vertical or horizontal (0°, 90°, 180°, 270°). I need to find intersection point of these two segments. I need also calculate the intersection point if both segments are vertical or horizontal. Thank you.

[image]

Comment: "If both segments are parallel, I need to calculate the intersection point too"???

Comment: So, ignoring your funny requirement ("find the intersection of two parallel lines"), you have lines `x = x_0` and `y = y_0` and you wonder how to find the intersection point `(x_0, y_0)`?... I don't see any open issues

Comment: Parallel lines may intersect only when the lines are collinear. There can be more than one intersection points in such cases.

Comment: Re: find the intersection of two parallel lines: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BKorP55Aqvg

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 point P1[(x1,y1),(x2,y2)] and P2[(x1,y1),(x2,y2)].

Since the lines are either horizontal or vertical, one line will have a x constant and the other has a y constant.

So for each point check if x1 = x2 and it true make x = x1. Similarly if y1=y2, make y = y2.
(x,y) is your intersection point.

If either x or y remains null at the end, then it means the lines are parallel hence no intersection. (If lines are parallel, the same variable will vary)

Comment: These are segments, not lines. there could be 0 intersection between them (and it is easy to check if it is indeed the case)

Comment: Added that part. Had not mentioned as a trivial case. Hope this makes sense